# Is there a way to scan for viruses when downloading an attachment using EWS?

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I have an application which downloads emails/attachments from Exchange Web Service. I want to know if there's a way I can scan for viruses before I attempt to download it. I haven't had any luck in finding it.

Thank you

Comment: You cannot scan unless the file is local as it's inside the message. You are better off enabling virus scan on Exchange itself.

Comment: innocent until proven guilty. Code is guilty until proved innocent. Therefore passing through a virus scanner is no proof that it is safe. Don't run un-trusted code on your computer. And if you run Microsoft's windows, you will be hacked, wipe it clean at the end of the day.

Comment: ok, I'll try to do that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remotely check if it has any viruses.
What I would do is first download the file in a `temp` directory, then run a batch file to scan it with any installed anti virus.

I'd personally use *Windows Defender*: you can find the [command line instruction here](https://superuser.com/questions/481862/how-can-you-scan-from-the-command-line-with-windows-defender) on how to run a scan from `cmd.exe`

As for how to start `cmd.exe` with preconfigured startup commands, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549227/executing-command-line-exe-with-parameters-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks, I thought of doing that, but was wondering if there's a way I can scan before downloading it.

Comment: In an antivir company they had a computer with several antivirus scanners. All had console based analysis and was very trustworthy. Kinda hard to setup it on your own rho