# Selenium headless browser testing using Triflejs

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-11, visual-studio-2019, headless-browser, triflejs

I am having some UI testcases, which are run using a Azure DevOps release pipeline. These testcases are working in Chrome and Firefox when I enable headless mode.

Now I want to enable a headless mode for Internet Explorer(IE11). When I searched on the web I found that this can be achieved using TrifleJs. How can implement TrifleJs in Visual Studio 2019? Can somebody provide the C# code?

Browser : IE11,
Server : Windows Server 2019 Datacenter

Comment: From your description, it seems that you want to execute the TrifleJs command line in C#, please refer to the following links to use the Process.Start() method executes the command: [Executing Command line .exe with parameters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549227/), [Run an exe from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679375/) and [Run command line code programmatically using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738168/). Besides, I suggest you check the [System Requirements](https://github.com/sdesalas/trifleJS) and the browser compatibility, make sure it works.

Comment: hey, I have updated the question.

Comment: Could you figure out something? I'm also stuck at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,  IE does not have support for a headless mode.

From the [TrifleJs document](https://triflejs.org/), the TrifleJs is a kind of browser that can emulate some IE versions in a headless mode and execute JavaScript script, since its coded as a port of PhantomJS.

At present, it is an executable file, instead of a kind of SDK or API, so, we could not directly add it in C# application. I suggest you could check the document to use this tool, and you could also feedback this issue to [trifleJS forum](https://github.com/sdesalas/trifleJS/issues)